# Listview delete item and Refresh

Tags: android, listview, android-studio, page-refresh, uirefreshcontrol

hello i need some help ... i write this code but i am little confused when i add book to my fav it store to fav when i click on un fav there in fav list the book are still there in that activity until i don't close the activity when i reopen that fav activity the book are removed from there i want to add code that can refresh by self at that time when i un fav the book ... please help me out

```
public class Favrt extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {
ListView viewF;
Books_Adapter fav_adapter;
String[] name, links, author;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_favrt);
    fetch_fav();
    fav_adapter = new Books_Adapter(this, name, links, author);
    viewF = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.favView);
    viewF.setAdapter(fav_adapter);
    viewF.setOnItemClickListener(this);
}
public void fetch_fav(){
    SQLiteDatabase database = openOrCreateDatabase("Pdf_books",MODE_PRIVATE,null);
    Cursor db_cursor = database.rawQuery("select * from favourite", null);
    name = new String[db_cursor.getCount()];
    links = new String[db_cursor.getCount()];
    author = new String[db_cursor.getCount()];
    int i =0;
    if (db_cursor.moveToLast()){
        do {
        name[i] = db_cursor.getString(db_cursor.getColumnIndex("name"));
        links[i] = db_cursor.getString(db_cursor.getColumnIndex("links"));
        author[i] = db_cursor.getString(db_cursor.getColumnIndex("author"));
        i++;
        }while (db_cursor.moveToPrevious());
    }

    database.close();
}



    @Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    Intent web = new Intent(this, web_activity.class);
    web.putExtra("url", links[position]);
    startActivity(web);

}

@Override
public void onContentChanged() {
    super.onContentChanged();

    View empty = findViewById(R.id.empty);
    ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.favView);
    list.setEmptyView(empty);


}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Try `fav_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` after changing your list items (in this case, when your favorites are changed).

Answer (score 0):

You have to update adapter. to do so `fav_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`. which will make changes to listview.
make function in activity where you do such things like remove from db and update list data.